# HTML header rows if screen size is smaller

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good day, I am trying to be consistent on the interface aspect of my website. Right now I am trying to make the list in my header become rows if I adjust my screen size to a smaller size. I am stuck in figuring out how to make it into rows if I place multiple links in one div class row. Thanks for any help I can get.

HTML:

```
<div class="bg-color-white strong">
      <div class="container">
        <nav>
          <div class="row spacer">
            <div class="col-md-1">
              <div class="logo">
                <a href="home/../"><img src="img/logo_png_solo.png"></a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
              <ul class="list1">
                <li><a href="main" style="font-size: 26px;">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="faq" style="font-size: 26px;">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact" style="font-size: 26px;">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">

                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <a href="../signout" class="small color-orange">Sign Out</a>
                <hr>

              <ul class="list2">
                  <li><a href="cards" class="ul_login" style="font-size: 26px;">Login</a></li>
                  <li><a href="cards/register.php" class="ul_reg" style="font-size: 26px;">Register</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
```

[image: small screen]

EDIT: what i want is to have all the links automatically be in a row if the screen size is smaller, if I add lg, md, sm three of my links are still in one row.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/61kc2hjx/

[image: goal]

Comment: I would increase the first div from col-md-8 to col-md-12 and then remove the div with col-md-3 and add to the UL class="list2" a pull-right class. Additionally depending on the browsers that you are looking to support you should take a look at the @media property and make changes in your css there. also some older browsers will not recognise `<nav>` its safe to replace this with a `<div>`

Comment: but the header when the screen is at full size is not on one row anymore

Comment: Ah make it col-md-11 didn't see the previous div taking up 1 col.

Comment: i get the column sizes but what i want is to have all the links automatically be in a row if the screen size is smaller, if I add lg, md, sm three of my links are still in one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-4"></div>
</div>
```

The `.col` div will have full width by default. But as the screen gets larger, the col width will decrease progressively. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jm56Z/aq9Laaew/263819/)

### Edit #1 :

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-8">
    <div class="list1 row">
        <a class="col col-4 col-md-12">Home</a>
        <a class="col col-4 col-md-12">FAQ</a>
        <a class="col col-4 col-md-12">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jm56Z/aq9Laaew/263849/)
*This is what I understood from your explanations. But I hope you get the idea.*

Comment: i get the column sizes but what i want is to have all the links automatically be in a row if the screen size is smaller, if I add lg, md, sm three of my links are still in one row. https://jsfiddle.net/61kc2hjx/

Comment: With bootstrap you can remove `<ul><li>` divs ([Doc.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/#links-and-buttons)). This way you can change the width of you links to make them fit in one row or not. I'm editing my answer to give an example.